# Create View with Unique Key and Group By Multiple Parameters

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-view, unique-key

I've been creating a view with this statement

```
SELECT  
    CAST(tt.DateTimeScanned as date) AS ForDate,
    DATEPART(hour,tt.DateTimeScanned) AS OnHour,
    COUNT(*) AS Totals
FROM 
    Transaction_Tickets tt
WHERE 
    tt.TicketId = 156 AND IsCancelled = 0 AND IsScanned = 1
GROUP BY 
    CAST(tt.DateTimeScanned as date),
    DATEPART(hour,tt.DateTimeScanned)
```

Current output is

```
ForDate      OnHour    Totals
-------------------------------
2019-05-05   10        2021
2019-05-05    7         323
2019-05-05   13         692
2019-05-04   15         373
2019-05-05   16         230
2019-05-05   19           3
```

However, it does not have a unique column so when I save it as a view and update my model on my MVC project, it does not apply my new created view since it does not have the proper key on it.

When I view the design of my other working views, I saw this primary key symbol

[image]

While viewing this newly created view gives me this error

[image]

So my question is how can I achieve including a unique key to my view without affecting the group by clause?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a row number to your view.  You can change the `ORDER BY` clause, I'm just assuming you'd want to use your date filed.

```
SELECT  
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CAST(tt.DateTimeScanned as date)) AS MyRowNumber,
   CAST(tt.DateTimeScanned as date) AS ForDate,
    DATEPART(hour,tt.DateTimeScanned) AS OnHour,
    COUNT(*) AS Totals
FROM Transaction_Tickets tt
where tt.TicketId = 156 and IsCancelled = 0 and IsScanned = 1
GROUP BY CAST(tt.DateTimeScanned as date),
   DATEPART(hour,tt.DateTimeScanned)
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I tried your solution, the view was created successfully, but when I tried to update my model on my project solution, it doesn't get the update